# Error: Pchart and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pchart

I will explain my error:
I have a form where I type an email shortly after it sends to ConexaoDB.php this page, I store the entered value, connect the PostgreSQL go into the users table and when the email entered and found I store the value in a variable coluna_empresa. and this variable has the same name as a database in MySQL, make sure the connection Mysql, so far so good when I try to take a more include ('ConexaoDB.php') in my page to generate a graph have the following errors:

when I open at the same time: This "http: //localhost/grafico/example.mysql2.php" contains errors and can not be displayed.

After having sent the values:

Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/www/grafico/db/ConexaoDB.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: nome in /var/www/grafico/db/ConexaoDB.php on line 26

No database selected

I need you guys help. put the codes below:

example.mysql2.php:

```
<?php
/* Incluindo classes do pChart */
 include("class/pData.class.php");
 include("class/pDraw.class.php");
 include("class/pImage.class.php");
include("db/ConexaoDB.php");

 /* Criando o objeto pData */
$myData = new pData();

/* Construindo a consulta e retornando os dados para o grafico*/
$Requete = "SELECT * FROM `marca`";
$Result  = mysql_query($Requete);
$cod=""; $bom=""; $regular=""; $ruim="";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
          {
                 /*  Puxando os resultados da consulta em um array*/
                     $cod[]   = $row["cod_pesquisa"];
                     $bom[] = $row["bom_twitter"];
                     $regular[]    = $row["regular_twitter"];
                     $ruim[]    = $row["ruim_twitter"];
           }

/* Salvando os dados no array pData*/
$myData->addPoints($cod,"Cod");
$myData->addPoints($bom,"Gostou");
$myData->addPoints($regular,"Indiferente");
$myData->addPoints($ruim,"Nao gostou");

//Definindo um sistema de cores das barras
$myData->loadPalette("palettes/notion.color",TRUE);

/*  Colocando a coluna cod_pesquisa como eixo das abscissa*/
$myData->setAbscissa("Cod");

/* Declarando o eixo Y e dando seu nome */
$myData->setAxisName(0,"Twetts");

/*Criando um objeto pChart*/
$myPicture = new pImage(700,230,$myData);

/*Configurando o fundo da imagem*/
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,700,230,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,array("StartR"=>40,"StartG"=>40,"StartB"=>40,"EndR"=>80,"EndG"=>80,"EndB"=>80,"Alpha"=>100));

 //Cabeçalho da imagem
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,700,35,DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL,array("StartR"=>0,"StartG"=>0,"StartB"=>0,"EndR"=>0,"EndG"=>0,"EndB"=>0,"Alpha"=>220));

 /* Adicionando bordas a imagem */
 $myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,699,229,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));

 /* Selecionando sistemas da fonte */
 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255,"FontName"=>"fonts/pf_arma_five.ttf","FontSize"=>6));

/*Criando titulo */
 $myPicture->drawText(220,25,"Analise de Sentimento - Marca",array("FontSize"=>15,"Align"=>TEXT_ALIGN_BOTTOMMIDDLE, "R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255));

 /* Definindo a área do gráfico */
 $myPicture->setGraphArea(60,40,650,200);

 /* Desenhando a escala */
 $scaleSettings = array("GridR"=>50,"GridG"=>50,"GridB"=>50,"DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE,"CycleBackground"=>TRUE);
 $myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings);

 /* Escrevendo a area da legenda */
 $myPicture->drawLegend(520,12,array("Style"=>LEGEND_NOBORDER,"Mode"=>LEGEND_HORIZONTAL));

 /* Ligando sombras */
 $myPicture->setShadow(TRUE,array("X"=>1,"Y"=>1,"R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0,"Alpha"=>5));

 /* Desenhando grafico */
 $settings = array("Gradient"=>TRUE,"GradientMode"=>GRADIENT_EFFECT_CAN,"DisplayPos"=>LABEL_POS_INSIDE,"DisplayValues"=>TRUE,"DisplayR"=>255,"DisplayG"=>255,"DisplayB"=>255,"DisplayShadow"=>TRUE);
 $myPicture->drawBarChart($settings);

 /* Fazendo a imagem ( Escolha um bom caminho para a imagem) */
 $myPicture->autoOutput("example.mysql.png");
?>
```

ConexaoDB.php:

```
 <?php

        require_once"Conexao.classPg.php";
        require_once "Conexao.classMysql.php";


        $conexao = New Conexao;
        //conexao PostgreSql
        $conexao->conectarPostgreSql();

           $email = $_POST['email'];

            $sql = "SELECT nome_empresa FROM cadastros.usuarios where email = '".$email."' ";
            $query = pg_query($sql);

            while ($sql = pg_fetch_array($query)){

            $nome = $sql ['nome_empresa'];
            }

        //conexao Mysql
        $conexao2 = New ConexaoMysql;
        $conexao2->servidor = 'localhost';
        $conexao2->usuario = 'root';
        $conexao2->senha = 'sap';
                $conexao2->db = $nome;
        $conexao2->conectar();
                $conexao2->selectDB();

?>
```